# React FullCalendar - Showing additional data on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

I am newbie using react and full calendar, and i have page like this image.
[image: React fullcalendar]

Then, i have list of event like this:

```
    id: "9",
    eventId: "1",
    title: "Training Network",
    start: "2023-08-01T08:00:00",
    end: "2023-08-01T12:00:00",
    extendedProps: {
      department: "BioChemistry",
    },
  },
  {
    id: "10",
    eventId: "1",
    title: "Training Network",
    start: "2023-08-01T08:00:00",
    end: "2023-08-01T12:00:00",
    extendedProps: {
      organization: "DPR",
    },
  },
```

Do you know how to showing extendedProp into page on image above, since i declare the the fullcalendar like this below

```
<FullCalendar
            plugins={[
              dayGridPlugin,
              timeGridPlugin,
              interactionPlugin,
              listPlugin,
            ]}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: "prev,next",
              center: "title",
              right: "timeGridDay,listDay",
            }}
            initialView="timeGridDay"
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            selectMirror={true}
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            weekends={weekendsVisible}
            select={handleClickDate}
            initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS}
            initialDate={result}
            eventClick={handleEventClick}
            eventsSet={handleEvents}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Based on documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react)
Adding this prop to

```
<FullCalendar eventContent={renderEventContent} {..otherPorps} />
```

Creating a **renderEventContent** function will suffice the requirement

```
function renderEventContent(eventInfo) {
  return (
    <>
      <b>{eventInfo.extendedProps.organization}</b>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Ok, i am trying it now